# How can clearing your browser's history solve an issue with a website?

Tags: web, web-applications, browser-history

What is a situation where nothing more than clearing your browser history will solve an issue with a web application?

"Clearing your history" does **not** include cookies or any sort of cache. Just the history. Is there any legitimate situation where asking someone to clear their browser history will solve a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There should never be such a situation, so, "none".

Longer answer: Well there are some possible interactions with history (window.history.go comes to mind) and it's possible that some websites could use some very convoluted systems to examine and ingest that history/.
  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API for some brief overviews on how mozilla based browsers would do it)

But those are all nonsensical, unreliable, and remarkably bad design decisions for a web application to make.  If you can clear your browser history and solve a problem with a web application, that web application is categorically awful and you should not use it.

EDIT:  This presumes you're talking about location history.  If you're asking how clearing the other historical data in your browser (such as cookies or cached data or local storage or perhaps download history) might affect the experience. there are plenty of ways that could affect the function of a site!